# Pull List Account structure Ga4 + export Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to pull my Account structure from GA4 in bulk. I have found several scripts but nothing works perfectly (info would be, account title, property ID & Stream ID).

Google provides a script for GA3 but not for Ga4 > [App script sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics#sample_code)

I have found this one but the code in the answer was still not working + has a max cap of 50 accounts. While mine has more than 200. > [Pull List of GA4 Properties Using Google Analytics Admin API and App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71772152/1841839).

An output report would be really nice.

A big plus would be that it export also in a google sheets document. I saw something similar in stack overflow > [GA4 | Google Analytics Admin API | Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769210/ga4-google-analytics-admin-api-apps-script)

Because my Javascript skills are only reading and some copy/pasting, I am not able to fix this problem by myself.

Could someone help me, please? Thanks in advance!

I have tried to find all the documentation in that way people understand what I want to create and where to find the documentation.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] describe your issue, error messages and what you have done to fix it.    **Note stack overflow is not a coding service.  We are not going to do your work for you.**

Comment: You should look into the API response of the accountSummaries endpoint. It may be that it employs pagination. And that pagination wasn't taken into account in the answer you've linked. [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accounts/list?authuser=0) Looks like they do employ pagination indeed.